# deleting a record in linq to sql (vb.net) what is wrong with my code?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am getting the correct Employee Id in the VarEmpID variable. When I click on delete 
It is giving me

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Linq.DataQuery`1[my name space]' to type 'namespace'.

enter code here

```
    Protected Sub radGrid1_DeleteCommand(ByVal source As Object, ByVal e As  GridCommandEventArgs) Handles radGrid1.DeleteCommand

          Dim VarEmpId As String = (CType(e.Item, GridDataItem)).OwnerTableView.DataKeyValues(e.Item.ItemIndex)("EmpId").ToString()

          Using dc1 As New EmployeesDataClassesDataContext()

            Dim EmployeeEntry = (From p In dc1.Employees
            Where (p.EmpId = VarEmpId)
                                Select p)

            dc1.Employees.DeleteOnSubmit(EmployeeEntry)
            dc1.SubmitChanges()

            Dim queryResults = (From queryItem In EmployeeEntry Select queryItem).ToList()
            If queryResults.Any Then
                radGrid1.DataSource = queryResults
                radGrid1.DataBind()
            End If

        End Using



    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dc1.Employees.DeleteOnSubmit(EmployeeEntry)
```

That method expects an Employee instance.  Instead, you passed in an employee query.

```
Dim EmployeeEntry = ( query )
```

This is a query, not an entry.  Consider calling Enumerable.First to get the first result of the query, and then deleting that.

Comment: Modified added Dim EmployeeEntry = (From p In dc1.Employees
            Where (p.EmpId = VarEmpId)
                                Select p).singleorDefault() After that commented out the queryresults part and binded data again it solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Modified added Dim EmployeeEntry = (From p In dc1.Employees Where (p.EmpId = VarEmpId) Select p).singleorDefault() After that commented out the queryresults part and binded data again it solved my problem. – SmilingLily